# How to delete an entry from NSDictionary which is the element of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a problem which I can't solve for a long time. I have a JSON response from the server which is parsed to NSDictionary lastMsgs as in the image below:
[image]

So for example 1323 it's a key and it associated with NSDictionary (which contains  keys such as body, subject etc and values). So the problem I need in some way delete an entry which nested NSDictionary value  has entry : type = 1. I don't know how to do this. I tried to do this:

```
  NSMutableArray* _ModelVals = [[lastMsgs allValues] mutableCopy];
    for (int i =0; i<[_ModelVals count]; i++) {
        string_compare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , [_ModelVals objectAtIndex:i]];
        if ([string_compare rangeOfString:@"type = 1"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [_ModelVals removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }

    }
```

But it is work not correctly and delete not all entries which has type = 1.

So the question -  how can I implement this and delete entry in nested NSDictionary?

Comment: Why don't you make the dictionary mutable with `NSMutableDictionary`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no value "type = 1" in the dictionary. That's just the log. You get the value of a key in a dictionary using `[dict objectForKey:@"key"]` or `dict[@"key"]`.

Judging from your log, the type seems to be an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. Just get the `int` representation of it (assuming the type is an integer) and use a simple C `int` to `int` comparison.

And you can't filter an array like that. You will skip an entry. If you remove an entry, you have to decrease `i` by `1`.

Or use this simpler solution:

```
NSSet *keys = [lastMsgs keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj[@"type"] intValue] == 1;
}];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [lastMsgs mutableCopy];
[dict removeObjectsForKeys:[keys allObjects]];
```

This will first collect the keys of all objects (dictionaries) that have a type of `1` and then remove those from a mutable copy of the original dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for this but can you explain in more details your simpler solution?I don't fully understand your block code.

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysOfEntriesPassingTest:). It's a simple way to filter dictionaries. You specify a block with some kind of test. The dictionary will then run this test with all key/value pairs (those are the first 2 parameters of the block). If your block returns `YES` for a key/value pair, the key will be added to the set that is returned at the end.

Comment: In the block I simply get the value for the key `type` of the current entry, get its `int` representation and compare it to 1. The comparison will result in a boolean value (`YES` if it's 1, `NO` otherwise), which I return from the block.

Comment: Thanks but I knew this I mean that I don't understand this line: return [obj[@"type"] intValue] == 1 becaue type is a value of a nested NSDictionary how can I access it?

Comment: "In the block I simply get the value for the key type of the current entry" but as I wrote "type is a value of a nested NSDictionary how can I access it?" So I don't undersand this thing. Sorry if it is a silly question

Comment: Sorry once again I really was a dummy:)Now I understood

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add or remove objects from a collection while enumerating though it. I would create a another array that you can store references to the objects that you want to delete and remove them after you have looped though it.